# Rotate PDF pages: 90 degrees for even pages and -90 degrees for odd pages

Tags: pdf, pdftk

In a PDF file, how to rotate pages 90 degrees for even pages and -90 degrees for odd pages?

With [PDFtk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFtk), all I know is to rotate a single page:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1W output out.pdf
```

And rotate all pages:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endW output out.pdf
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is easy since pdftk 1.44 which added the `shuffle` operation allowing different transformations on odd and even pages (amongst other uses).

If you have an older version of pdftk, you can use this Python script with the [PyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) library. (Warning, typed directly into the browser.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input = PdfFileReader(sys.stdin)
output = PdfFileWriter()
for i in range(0,input.getNumPages()):
    output.addPage(input.getPage(i).rotateClockwise(90 if i%2==0 else -90))
output.write(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 40):

With `pdftk` version [1.45 (6 December 2012)](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/) or later, use:

```
pdftk A=MyPdfFile.pdf shuffle AoddWest AevenEast output MyRotatedFile.pdf
```

If you have `pdftk` version [1.44](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/) ([thanks to Gilles for pointing that out!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/rotate-pdf-pages-90-degree-for-even-pages-and-90-degree-for-odd-pages/18631#18631)), you can use:

```
pdftk A=MyPdfFile.pdf shuffle AoddL AevenR output MyRotatedFile.pdf
```

<sub>Some similar example cases are described in `man pdftk` (at least in recent versions).</sub>

Comment: rotate even pages by 180 degrees: `pdftk A=infile.pdf shuffle Aoddnorth Aevensouth output outfile.pdf` ([source](https://gist.github.com/sepastian/7ea8fa2959bd447392648e284fdc9d34))

Answer (score 2):

As an improvement to [Gilles's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) answer:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input = PdfFileReader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
for i in range(0,input.getNumPages()):
    output.addPage(input.getPage(i).rotateClockwise(90 if i%2==0 else -90))
output.write(open(sys.argv[2], "wb"))
```

Where the program accepts command line arguments of an input and output file: `python script.py <inputFileName> <outputFileName>`

Answer (score 2):

## With [QPDF](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf)

```
qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=+90:1-z:even --rotate=-90:1-z:odd
```

See the documentation for [more](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#option-rotate).