# Rotate every other page with pdfjam

Tags: pdf

I want to rotate every odd page 180 degrees **using `pdfjam`**.

I do not want to use `pdftk`, as in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/rotate-pdf-pages-90-degree-for-even-pages-and-90-degree-for-odd-pages). The command seems to be `pdf180` (for `pdfjam` before version 3.02), but the selection does not seem to take rules like odd/even pages. Also, if I skip pages, the new document does not include them. Thus, the command

```
pdf180 file.pdf 1,3,5,7,9                # for pdfjam < 3.02
pdfjam --angle 180 file.pdf 1,3,5,7,9    # for pdfjam >= 3.02
```

produces a file without pages 2, 4, 6, and 8.

Also, I have a large document, so I would like to save space when writing this. I cannot see anything useful in `pdfjam --help`.

How can I achieve this goal?

If a one-line command cannot produce this, I guess I could write a script, which produces `$N$` number of rotated files, and then merge them.

Comment: Strange, I have `pdfjam` installed but no `pdf180`. It seems I won't be able to help.

Comment: @bela83 Which version do you have? If I type `pdfjam` or `pdf180` I get `pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.`

Comment: OK I get it! I have version 3.03 and some wrapper scripts were removed from the pdfjam package at version 3.02:
https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam#-wrapper-scripts-no-longer-included-here

Comment: @bela83 Interesting. I need to update my Ubuntu urgently! (16.04). I updated the post with the indirect command that does the same.

Answer (score 4):

For anybody who's not tied to pdfjam, you can do this with [QPDF](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) as well:

```
qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=+180:1-z:odd
```

See QPDF's [documentation](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your shoes I'd split the document in as many files as the pages, rotate only odd ones, and merge all the pages back together.

Answer (score 1):

Using pipe with `pdfjam` can do the task. Rotate some pages and write to `stdout`. Then, throw pipe, read other pages from original file merged with the rotated pages from `stdin`.

For example, the code below rotates some pages to generate a PDF booklet with 2x2 pages per sheet side, double sided (`file.pdf` contains 8 pages):

```shell
pdfjam file.pdf '5,4,7,2' --no-landscape --angle 180 -o /dev/stdout | pdfjam file.pdf '8,1' /dev/stdin '1,2' file.pdf '6,3' /dev/stdin '3,4' --no-landscape --nup 2x2 -o out.pdf
```